# How to use VScode live server when you are working on XAMPP?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, xampp

Recently, I was working with XAMPP and now when I'm trying to open my html code with VScode live server, it shows the listing directory of XAMPP htdocs. What should I do?

Comment: Typically a webserver will look for a file called `index.htm` (or *.php or *.html etc) to serve it. Do you have such a file? If not try to rename your main webpage file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your project in VS Code and click on Go Live from StatusBar to turn on/off the server.
2. Right click on a HTML file from Explorer Window & click to Open with Live Server.
3. Open a HTML file and Right click on the editor and choose the options.

if you don't have have any .html or .htm file in your project then you have these steps:

1. Hit (alt+L, alt+O) to Open the Server and (alt+L, alt+C) to Stop the server (You can change the shortcut form keybinding). [On MAC, cmd+L, cmd+O and cmd+L, cmd+C]
2. Press F1 or ctrl+shift+P and type Live Server: Open With Live Server to start a server or type Live Server: Stop Live Server to stop a server.

I hope this will resolve your issue.